# Why my screen is divided into four parts

Tags: display, screen

[Screen divided into 4 different colours parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rw6o.jpg)

Comment: We'll need to know a bit more information to help solve this problem. Is this a new installation of Ubuntu? Do you have an Nvidia graphics card? Can you go into the Terminal (`ctrl`+`alt`+`T`), type `xrandr`, and share the output with us here?